# Correct way of wrapping javascript class in AngularJS module and inject angular services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

Inside an AngularJS module I'm developing, I have a `Canvas` class defined as:

```
angular.module("myModule", [])
.factory("Canvas", function() {return Canvas;});

var Canvas = function(element, options) {
    this.width = options.width || 300;
    this.height = options.height || 150;
    this.HTMLCanvas = $(element).get(0);
    this.HTMLCanvas.width = canvas.width;
    this.HTMLCanvas.height = canvas.height;
    this.objects = [];
    //Initialize canvas
    this.init();
}
Canvas.prototype.init = function() {/*...*/};
Canvas.prototype.otherMethod = function() {/*...*/};
```

Now, the `Canvas` class is never instantiated from inside the module, but rather from an AngularJS controller, like so:

```
angular.module("myApp.controllers", ["myModule"])
.controller("MainCtrl", ["Canvas", function(Canvas) {
    var canvas = new Canvas("#canvas", {/*options object*/});
    //...
}]);
```

And so far everything works like a charm.
But then I realized that I need the `$q` service in my canvas object, and since I don't want to resort to injecting it into my controller and then passing it to the `Canvas` constructor, I thought of modifying my module like so:

```
angular.module("myModule", [])
.factory("Canvas", ["$q", function(q) {
    var that = this;
    that.q = q;
    return function() {
        Canvas.apply(that, arguments);
    };
}]);

var Canvas = function(element, options) {
    console.log(this.q, element, options);
    this.width = options.width || 300;
    this.height = options.height || 150;
    this.HTMLCanvas = $(element).get(0);
    this.HTMLCanvas.width = canvas.width;
    this.HTMLCanvas.height = canvas.height;
    this.objects = [];
    //Initialize canvas
    this.init();
}
Canvas.prototype.init = function() {/*...*/};
Canvas.prototype.otherMethod = function() {/*...*/};
```

The initial `console.log` correctly logs the `$q` service and the `Canvas`'s original arguments, `element` and `options`, but breaks on the call to its `init` method:

`TypeError: undefined is not a function`

I suppose that's because `this` is no longer an instance of `Canvas` but rather of the anonymous function `function(q) {...}`.
Any hints on how I can instantiate new `Canvas` objects with the `q` property and still retain the class's methods?

**EDIT**

I've modified my code slightly to give a better idea of what I'd like to achieve:

```
angular.module("myModule", [])
//.factory("Canvas", function() {return Canvas;})
//.factory("Canvas", ["$q", CanvasFactory])

function CanvasFactory(q) {
    var canvas = this;
    canvas.q = q;
    return function() {
        Canvas.apply(canvas, arguments);
    };
}

var Canvas = function(element, options) {
    console.log(this instanceof Canvas, typeof this.q !== "undefined");
};
```

If I uncomment the first factory, `console.log` yields `true false`, whereas the second factory yields `false true`. My goal is to get `true true`, which means that `this` is in fact an instance of the `Canvas` class *and* has the `q` property defined. Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
angular.module("myModule", [])
.factory("Canvas", ["$q", function(q) {
    Canvas.prototype.q = q;
    return Canvas;
}]);

var Canvas = function(element, options) {
    console.log(this instanceof Canvas, typeof this.q !== "undefined");
};
```

This logs: `true true`.

Answer (score 1):

I create Canvas service like this and is work:

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.factory("Canvas", ["$q", function($q) {

    var Canvas = function(element, options) {
        this.q = $q;

        this.init();
        console.log(this.q, element, options);
    }
    Canvas.prototype.init = function() {/*...*/};
    Canvas.prototype.otherMethod = function() {/*...*/};

    return Canvas;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Canvas', function($scope, Canvas) {
    console.log( new Canvas().q );  
}]);
```

Also you can see this on Pluncer [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2JYVpE)

Comment: Thanks, that's a valid way but it would require writing the `Canvas` class *inside* the factory function, which somewhat limits the possibility of, say, reusing it elsewhere inside the module or factoring it out on a separate file. Hence I upvoted, but will accept my own answer since I figured it out in the meantime! :)